# Add a title to a new window in Titanium

Tags: mobile, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to open a new window via a button to the configuration page but how do you add a title (at the top of the screen) to a newly created window?

On the starting page, I have a button created to open a new page as:

```
var btnConfig = Ti.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage:'img/settings.png',
    height:33,
    width:33
});
win1.rightNavButton = btnConfig;

btnConfig.addEventListener('click',function(){
    Ti.include('win_config.js');
})
```

Then on win_config.js :

```
var win_config = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:"Configure",    
    backgroundColor:'#BBB',
});

win_config.open({
    transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT
});
```

I thought that by just setting "title" it'll appear but apparently it doesnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to add "modal:true" in the createWindow

```
var win_config = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:"Configure",    
    backgroundColor:'#BBB',
    modal:true

});
```